# How to make stored procedure in if..End if condition

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am beginner at stored procedures. I tried the following stored procedure in `IF...End If` condition so how to make it ... I am confused.... so anyone create it

```
strSql = "SELECT count(*) " & _
         " FROM hist_billgen_report r, hist_billgen_header h " & _
         " WHERE r.invoice_number=h.invoice_number " & _
         "   and h.macnum = '" & l_macnum & "' " & _
         "   and r.rep_type = 1 " & _
         "   and r.rep_call_type = '" & line_type & "' " & _
         "   and h.billing_job_id = '" & arg_job & "' "

         'Special code for data lines for Newcore
         If gcompany = "NCW" Then
            strSql += " and r.rep_number not in ( "

            strSql += "select distinct a.mdn from order_wireless a where"
            strSql += " a.id in"
            strSql += " ("
            strSql += " select c.serviceid from cust_charge_file b, service_charges c, main_company_utilities d"
            strSql += "                   where(b.chg_main_index = c.chargeid)"
            strSql += " and c.serviceid = a.id"
            strSql += " and (b.chg_main_category_id = d.utilities_id and d.utilities_type = 'CS' and (utilities_desc_short like '%FDS1%' or utilities_desc_short like '%FDS2%' or utilities_desc_short like '%FDS3%' or utilities_desc_short like '%MBS1%'  or utilities_desc_short like '%MBS2%'  or utilities_desc_short like '%MBS3%'  ) )"
            strSql += " )"
            strSql += " and a.accountnumber = '" & l_macnum & "' "
            strSql += " )"
        End If
```

Comment: What is it that you're confused about? What is your question?

Comment: how to implement it in if..end if condition for example how to declare variable for it..how to pass it just hint me   ..@Chris

Comment: This looks like a dynamic query... where does stored procedure come in?

Comment: ya..its dynamic query required to convert it in  store procedure for performance in vb.net project @Kritner

Answer (score 0):

Putting a query into a stored procedure doesn't necessarily always mean a performance increase.  Depending on the data in your tables, this query could be quite slow due to the `OR LIKES '%%'` in it, but you could do something like this:

```
create procedure [dbo].[spname]
    @l_macNum int -- note, you haven't given a lot of information, create all query parameters with appropriate types here
   -- more parameters
   @arg_job int -- same

AS
BEGIN

   if (@company = 'NCW')
       begin
                 SELECT count(*)
                 FROM hist_billgen_report r, hist_billgen_header h
                 WHERE r.invoice_number=h.invoice_number
                 and h.macnum = @l_macNum
                 -- etc
                 and r.rep_number not in (
                    -- etc
                 )

       end
   else
       begin
                 SELECT count(*)
                 FROM hist_billgen_report r, hist_billgen_header h
                 WHERE r.invoice_number=h.invoice_number
                 and h.macnum = @l_macNum
                 -- etc
       end

END
GO
```

note the If and else logic are completely separate queries, as you cannot do what I think you were hoping to do in a contiguous query, without using dynamic sql.  ***there are certain caveats to this but given you're new to sql, going to stick with that***

I used `-- etc` as place holders for your text, as I'm not going to provide the entire solution :P

If that doesn't make sense, let me know.